# como inicializar un string[] con un string-array de los recursos Android?

Tags: java, android

Que onda amigos, quisiera saber lo de la pregunta, lo que pasa es que yo tengo esto:

```
String[] data = {"Ejemplo 1", "Ejemplo 2", "Ejemplo 3", "Ejemplo 4"};
```

y tengo en mis recursos este arreglo de string:

```
<string-array
name="ejemplos">
    <item>Ejemplo 1</item>
    <item>Ejemplo 2</item>
    <item>Ejemplo 3</item>
    <item>Ejemplo 4</item>
</string-array>
```

me gustaria inicializar o igualar en la variable data el arreglo "ejemplos" de los recursos.

lo estoy intentando de esta manera pero me tira una excepcion

```
private String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ejemplos);
```

y este es el error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

espero respuetas, gracias de antemano

Comment: 1. Puedes crear la variable antes del `onCreate...`: Ejemplo: `String[] data;` 2. **Después del `onCreate...`** ya tienes disponible tu array, antes no:   `data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ejemplos);` Debe funcionar, si realmente el array ejemplos se encuentra en su sitio, claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu array está en el lugar correcto, en resources.

No puedes acceder a él antes de que los recursos hayan sido cargados.

Si procedes así debería funcionar:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    String[] data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tulayout);
        //Aquí los recursos han sido cargados, entonces puedes invocar el array

        data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ejemplos); 
        System.out.println (data);   

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //...
    }


  }
```

Comment: Muy correcto. El factor fundamental es la carga de recursos `super.onCreate`. El intentar obtener el array también fallaría aunque se separe la declaración de `data` de su inicialización si se hace donde aún no se hayan cargado los recursos.

Answer (score 1):

Estas obteniendo este error porque el acceso a los recursos requiere el contexto:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources
>   android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

el cual no puede ser obtenido al definir la obtenciòn de los valores del array.

```
private String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ejemplos);
```

---

Para solucionar esto, debes definir primeramente la variable del array:

```
private String[] data;
```

y posteriormente obtener los datos, recuerda que requieres el contexto, pero si estas dentro de una Activity simplemente puedes obtenerlos de esta forma:

```
data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ejemplos);
```